# How to learn to use autotools/libtool? (Does anybody dislike it too?)

Tags: autotools, libtool

When some project is having all that "ltmain", "aclocal.m4" and other "autogen.sh" it brings discomfort:

1. `./autogen.sh` is slow. `./configure` is slow.
2. `./configure` fails complaining missing somewthing. I fix it and it complains about something next. [Slow](https://superuser.com/questions/201585/speeding-up-configure-script-restarts-when-it-fails).
3. Makefiles are BIG. configure script is BIG. Even `configure.ac` is usually big and incomprehensible.
4. Makefile.am and configure.ac is full of mostly mysterious variables. How it deduces rules?
5. I *suddenly* realize that I copied only libtool's shell script stub and actual binary is in `.deps` or `.libs` or whatever.
6. In general if something is broken there I feel unsure what to do and error messages are usually confusing.
7. Finally, even small project is at least 50kb in archive when it have autotool's configure script (when the source code can be 5kb in archive).

Every problem with it adds more and more hate points to {auto,lib}tool.

How to get on well with that things? Is there a short tutorial (not longish "introduction to GNU Build System" or how is it called) plus comprehensive reference how to create, fix and debug that things?

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate, but even if it weren't, I'd close it as subjective and argumentative. :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn the Joy of Autotools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208168/how-to-learn-the-joy-of-autotools)

Comment: Those who don't understand it are doomed to dislike it.

Comment: There's no such thing as `configure.am`. You might be thinking of `configure.ac` in point 4.

Comment: People dislike it because they haven't written a ./configure script by hand

Comment: @alternative, Sometimes I create simple little bash-based "./configure" (that assumes good sane development-ready GNU/Linux and checks for some uncommon things).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html is a fantastic tutorial. Don't let the page count put you off: most of it is diagrams appearing piece by piece.

Comment: Looks like the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a book [GNU Autoconf, Automake and Libtool](http://sourceware.org/autobook/) published by New Riders. I own a copy, but can't strongly recommend it, mainly because I'm not really interested in the tools. It seems fairly authoritative though - authors are Red Hat people and GNU maintainers.

**Update:** It seems like the book's content is available on-line [here](http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html).