# How to create configure script for project?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, autotools, configure, polarssl

I would like to build [PolarSSL](http://polarssl.org) using

```
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32
```

but there is no configure script. I have read about [creating one using Autoconf](http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/autoconf-2.12/autoconf_2.html), but I did not have luck with it. To clarify, `--host` has been working for me because it sets everything for you, e.g.

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
i686-w64-mingw32-cc
i686-w64-mingw32-ar
i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib
```

without having to explicitly set all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the PolarSSL tarball, it seems you are out of luck. PolarSSL's build system is CMake, and it would take much more effort to convert that to an Autotools build system than it would be to just explicitly set your cross-compiling tools. [Here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling) is information on cross-compiling from the CMake wiki.

PS. If you ever do use Autoconf, that page you linked to is out of date.

Comment: Sure! There are some at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208168/how-to-learn-the-joy-of-autotools) and there's a short section on Autotools in a tutorial I've written myself on GTK programming: http://ptomato.github.com/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/real-life-app-setup.html

Comment: John Calcote's book, that @ptomato mentions, is terrific. After the years of arcane, piecemeal, learning, I wish I'd had it before trying to read the autotools manuals! If it was up to date with the latest releases, I'd really like to see it commissioned by O'Reilly's.

Comment: @BrettHale, that's my favorite too. It's already been published in book form though, by No Starch Press -- which has apparently been bought by O'Reilly? In any case you can order it from them: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593272067.do